# Extra output in program

Tags: c

I've been trying to create a program that prints a number in an array if the average of the subsequent numbers is less than the number.

Here's the code I wrote

```
            #include <stdio.h>

            int main(void) {
                int a,b[100],i,m,av=0,kk,p=0,q;
                scanf("%d",&a);
                for(i=0;i<a;i++)
                {
                    scanf("%d",&b[i]);
                }
                for(i=0;i<a;i++)
                {
                    kk=b[i];

                    for(m=i+1;m<a;m++)
                    {
                        av=av+b[m];
                        p=p+1;
                    }
                    q=av/p;
                    if(kk>q)
                    {
                        printf("%d\n",kk);
                    }
                }
            }
```

The input I took was 
7 - Number of elements

(now for the elements)

23

34

12

21

14

26

33

The output should be 34 and 33 but it is also showing 26 in the output. I've been trying to find the mistake but hitting a dead end.
Help is appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: You'll likely not wanting to be use `int` for the variable `q` - use a float or double. And I think you'll want to reset `av` and `p` each iteration of the outer `i` loop.

Comment: Just tried. Didn't work. Ty though

Comment: you'll still need to cast the operand to float or double like `q=(double)av/p;` to get a floating-point division even if q is a floating-point type

Comment: Actually resetting the value worked.. Ty

Comment: If you reset kv and p before the inner loop, it should work. And don't forget to skip the last number, otherwise you have a division by zero.

Answer (score 0):

**

### There are two mistakes you have made

**

1. when i is pointing to the last element m is checking for (i+1)th element that do not exist so make the loop till last but 1 element.
2. for each element after checking the average, make the av and p
   values 0. at last print the last element which is always true

   ```
          #include<stdio.h>
           int main(void) {
               int a,b[100],i,m,av=0,kk,p=0,q=0;
               scanf("%d",&a);
               for(i=0;i<a;i++)
               {
                   scanf("%d",&b[i]);
               }
               for(i=0;i<a-1;i++)
               {
                   kk=b[i];
                   av=0;
                   p=0;
                   for(m=i+1;m<a;m++)
                   {
                       av +=b[m];
                       p +=1;
                   }
                   q = av/p;
                   if(kk>q)
                   {
                       printf("%d ",kk);
                   }
               }
               if(i==a-1)
               {
                   printf("%d ",b[a-1]);
               }
           }
   ```